# Excel Index / Small, reducing multiple lines to a range

Tags: excel, indexing

I've got the below formula that I know can be reduced down, but am struggling.

It's an Index/Small taking out multiple string matches and blanks, which I know for sure can be changed to check a range. 
So if I was to put AL, SICK etc into range K1:K6, how can I achieve the same result referring to that range instead of lots of single lines?

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$37,SMALL(
IF(($H$4:$H$37<>"")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"AL")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"SICK")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"RDIL")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"TOIL")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"RD")
*($H$4:$H$37<>"DETACHED"),
ROW($H$4:$H$37)-ROW($H$4)+1,ROW($H$37)+1),1)),"")
```

I've tried a version of SUMPRODUCT, ISNA and COUNTIFS but am hitting the limit of my Excel knowledge. Anyone able to assist please?

Am happy to provide links to sheets etc if it helps.

Comment: Is your formula missing an IFERROR at the start? And does it currently work? Can you include some sample data and expected output as well?

Comment: Yeah apologies, i stripped the IFERROR from the beginning to make it more readable, but missed the "" at the end. Sorry! The current formula does work, but I'm not happy with the repetition that seems unnecessary. (and i'm looking to add another 10ish strings to it).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$37,SMALL(
IF(ISERROR(MATCH($H$4:$H$37,$A$1:$A$6,0)),
ROW($H$4:$H$37)-ROW($H$4)+1),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

**A1:A6 refers to**

AL

SICK

RDIL

TOIL

RD

DETACHED

Comment: Thank you! Seems i was over-complicating it, and this makes total sense. Very grateful for the prompt reply :)